# PHP: Using opendir to populate JS slideshow

Tags: php, javascript

I guess I'm having trouble mushing the scripts together. I can print the file names of the content in the folder, no problem. I've got the slideshow working when img urls are listed directed into the div. NOW I need to get the file name, and echo a .... somehow.

```
          <script type="text/javascript">

      function slideSwitch() {
          var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active');

          if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV:last');

          // use this to pull the divs in the order they appear in the markup
          var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
              : $('#slideshow DIV:first');

          // uncomment below to pull the divs randomly
          // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
          // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
          // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


          $active.addClass('last-active');

          $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
              .addClass('active')
              .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
                  $active.removeClass('active last-active');
              });
      }

      $(function() {
          setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
      });

      </script>


       <div id="slideshow">
       <?php
      $dir = "images/featured/";
      $dh = opendir($dir);
      while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
      echo "";
      }
      closedir($dh);
      ?>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing your JS and PHP as far as which does what. PHP is server-side while JS is client side (for your case). Once the content reaches the browser, PHP's job is done and JS's begins.

Your PHP code outputs nothing at all. Here's how it's being executed

1. You open the directory
2. Read the filenames one at a time
3. Echo an empty string

If you want to pass data from PHP to JS, you need to do something like

```
var phpData = <?php echo $dataIWantToAccessInJs; ?>;
```

Finally, you don't need to prefix your regular JS variables with the `$` sign. It is required in PHP though, but keeping the `$` for PHP (and jQuery objects) will cut down on the aforementioned confusion between JS and PHP.

Comment: I REALLY appreciate your advice. All of this aside, what is the best way of going about teaching myself PHP? My problem is that I haven't had the luxury of learning: A, B, C, D...I've had to jump straight in to resolve what our biz needed at the moment. (So I do know PHP w/ MySQL!)  Now I'd really like to learn the 'right' way. I've done W3 schools tutorial as well as others but I would like a more structured curriculum.

Comment: First off, I'd hire someone who knows what they're doing because webpages/applications not done right can hurt your business's bottom line in lost revenue/opportunities more so than hiring a professional. That shouldn't stop you from getting better at it yourself though. Just stick with either PHP or JS (each on its own) till you get good at both before trying to marry them in one page. If you feel confident enough, start trying to do your own scripts (not from a tutorial). Starting small and adding complexity the better you get.

Comment: Luckily I don't HAVE to use this method to display the 'slideshow'. I just thought being able to populate it dynamically from a directory with php would save time in the long run. Now, with the time I've put into it, it would take at least six months for that time to actually be saved. I'm throwing in the towel- and taking your advice to get to know PHP and JS better before marrying them. Just like real life :) Thank you again.